# sql connection suddenly raise error

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce, sqlconnection

I suddenly get this error while working in a non-relate part of my project 2 days ago :

> *Value of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection' cannot be converted to 'Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.SqlCeConnection'.*

This was working since I started working on my project. Anyone know why? I couldn't find any info as to what could cause this. And if I try to actually convert my `conn` object to a Microsoft connection I get a tons of more errors and nothing works ....

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports FinalH.FinalDataSet
Imports System.Data.SqlServerCe
Imports FinalH.FinalDataSetTableAdapters


Public Module conn

Public path As String = Application.StartupPath
Public ConString As String = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Final.sdf;Encrypt Database=True;Password=******;File Mode=shared read;Persist Security Info=False;"
Public con As New SqlCeConnection(ConString)
```

and in my login class

```
Private Sub LogIn_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
         daUsers.Connection = con
         UsersTable = daUsers.GetData()

    Catch fail As Exception
        MsgBox(fail.Message)
    End Try

    StartAndLoad()
End Sub
```

pretty simple stuff, and everything was ok I was working in a totally different class : I tried to convert a table type, didn't work, cancel and erase that class and suddenly I get these errors.

Comment: What type of object is `daUsers`?

Comment: its the data adapter for the users table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message, someone has changed the reference to the SqlServerCE dll. `Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.dll` is [only used for administering the SSCE DB from SQL Server Management Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171951%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and should not be used in an application.

Comment: ok and since I'm alone to code on this, how did I manage to change those references ?

I actually deleted the microsoft sql CE server references from my references, and it raised over 120 errors from the class build from the data set wizard. should I set it back or manually convvert everyone of those microsoft references to system.data.sqlceserver ?

Comment: ho well, I've updated the references for all the 512 Microsoft.sqlserverce to system.data.sqlserverce ... it stopped the warning and errors, hopefully it'll be the only thing I need to touch and it wont auto update next time I add a table.

Comment: Just for future reference and a recommendation; I would recommend a SQL helper class that handles your SQL connections and such. You then can just call the class and the function anywhere and get what you need...

Comment: well, I put them in a module instead of a helper class, does the same work no ?

Comment: I changed all references in the auto-generate code, dunno why is was done with the microsoft dll instead, but seems to work well now.